# C# WebAPI - get Azure App Service datacenter

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

We have internal metrics for our App Services we are already keeping and it would be helpful to know which location the request was served from (EastUS, westus, westeurope, etc).

How can I get that from within our WebAPI code?

Is that already encoded in the System.Environment.MachineName? or is there a SDK I need to add to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `REGION_NAME` environment variable.

Via Kudu DebugConsole -

```
D:\home>set REGION_NAME
REGION_NAME=West Europe
```

In Node that's `process.env.REGION_NAME`, so i guess for .NET that would be `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION_NAME")`.